# recommendation?: git repos on a shared drive or setting up a git server

Tags: git, version-control

If I see it correctly there are 2 possibilities to share a repo withhin a team:

1. bare repos are put on a shared windows drive, developers push/pull to this central repo.
2. a GIT server is setup , and developers push pull  to the server

What are advantages / disadvantages of the both?

Thx?

Comment: Can you clarify your situation?  Do you have fears about putting your code in the cloud? (e.g. some US Federal defense contractors certainly would)?  Do you, for some reason, need lightning fast response times from your Git server?

Comment: Well I work in a small company under 4 developers. Our boss doesnt want to put the code in a cloud based version control. So we have to do it internally. Easiest thing would be to use bare repos on a shared drive. Some clleagues are saying we should   use bare repos on a shared drive. For me that sounds strange. my feeling says I should use a dedicated git server. But what are advantages of using git server?

Comment: GitHub has a local enterprise option; you can basically use GitHub's interface, but nothing would ever leave your office (well, it wouldn't leave the server farm where your data is actually being stored).

Comment: FYI, Github Enterprise is much more expensive than using Gitlab Enterprise ($2500/yr vs. $156/yr for your user count of 4). Even at 10 users it's much cheaper (still $2500 for Github, $390 for Gitlab). _Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with Gitlab, but I do use their enterprise server._

Comment: what about bitbucket server? it s just 10$ per year for upto 10 users?

Answer (score 3):

Well a bare repository created with git init --bare is for… sharing. If you are collaborating with a team of developers, and need a place to share changes to a repo, then you will want to create a bare repository in centralized place where all users can push their changes (often the easy choice is github.com). Because git is a distributed version control system, no one will directly edit files in the shared centralized repository. Instead developers will clone the shared bare repo, make changes locally in their working copies of the repo, then push back to the shared bare repo to make their changes available to other users.

A working repository created with git init is for… working. It is where you will actually edit, add and delete files and git commit to save your changes. If you are starting a project in a folder on your dev machine where you will add, edit and delete files of your project, use “git init”. Note: if you git clone a repository you will be given a working repository with the .git folder and copies of the working files for editing.

Because no one ever makes edits directly to files in the shared bare repo, a working tree is not needed. In fact the working tree would just get in way and cause conflicts as users push code to the repository. This is why bare repositories exist and have no working tree.

Comment: Ok which troubles will you have if you use a dedicated git server versus when you use just a shared drive ?

Comment: Bare repository does not have a default remote origin repository so they don't allow you to git push and git pull

Answer (score 1):

As the whole, it’s depend on your preference. The advantage and disadvantage as below:

**Bare and with central repo** is easy to setup. But since the remote is bared, so you can’t view the codes in remote directly. And if you setup it on public path, you need pay attention to the access right and if it safe enough (the path can’t remove by others accidentaly).

For **git server**, it’s the typical way to git: remote and local repo model. But you need to spend more time to setup git server then bare repo.

And I'm used to use git server personally.